# Review Board installation "cryptography" error

Tags: review-board

When I try to install Review Board via this command on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo rb-site install /var/www/reviewboard.mysite.com
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rb-site", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'cryptography>=1.1' distribution was not found and is required by paramiko
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade cryptography
```